# Problema con uso de variables en funcion Mysql

Tags: mysql, funciones

Agradeceré su ayuda con la siguiente función en mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION diarios() 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE guias VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE recepcion VARCHAR(255);
    SET @fk_guias = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(g.id) FROM guias g WHERE g.fecha = '2021-12-01');
    SET @fk_recepcion = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(r.id) FROM recepciones r WHERE r.fk_guia in (@fk_guias));

    RETURN @fk_recepcion;
END
```

Si hago un `RETURN` a la variable `@fk_guias` el valor de la variable que devuelve al ejecutar la función es: 2487,3040,3041,3042,3043,3044,3045. Lo que es correcto. Este valor lo utilizo para la query siguiente pero el resultado es del tipo `3053` cuando debiera ser `3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060`

Al parecer la segunda query no toma todas condiciones en el `IN`, solo el primer número

¿Alguna idea de que pueda estar mal?

Comment: Te falta un parentesis en el primer set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador IN espera un conjunto de valores
mientras que `@fk_guias` es una cadena (un sólo valor); es como hacer:

```
WHERE r.fk_guia in ('3053,3054,3055,3056,3057,3058,3059,3060')
```

Donde ocurre una conversión automática de la cadena hacia el tipo -seguramente numérico- de `fk_guia`:

```
mysql> SELECT cast( '3053,3054,3055' as UNSIGNED );
+--------------------------------------+
| cast( '3053,3054,3055' as UNSIGNED ) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                 3053 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Para que funcione puedes usar `find_in_set()`:

```
SET @fk_recepcion = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(r.id)        
                       FROM recepciones r 
                       WHERE find_in_set(r.fk_guia, @fk_guias)
                    );
```

Bajo las siguientes advertencias:

1. Si en una base de datos relacional pretendes evitar las relaciones (JOINs) tienes un problema, el diseño y/o la herramienta no son los adecuados.
2. Hacer un JOIN en una consulta es de lo mas  normal/natural, no hay que tenerles miedo ¿Cuál es el problema de hacer el mismo JOIN dos o doscientas veces? Una cosa es racionalizar lo recursos, pero otra es inutilizarlos.
3. Las bases de datos relacionales manejan naturalmente renglones (registros), y algunos motores implementan **excepcionalmente** arreglos o valores separados por comas.

Dicho lo anterior, conviene considerar hacerlo con una sola consulta haciendo INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT group_concat(r.id) 
  FROM guias g 
    INNER JOIN recepciones r 
      ON r.fk_guia = g.id 
  WHERE g.fecha = '2021-12-01'
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta.

Si, había pensado en un principio hacer un JOIN, pero el resultado almacenado en @fk_guias lo voy a utilizar en otras consultas y espera aprovechar los datos que esa variable almacena.
¿Habrá algún modo de cambiar de cadena a conjunto de valores?

Veré que se puede hacer

Comment: La idea es poder usar los valores almacenados en las variables en otras sentencias incluidas unos delete y un inner join no funciona en el DELETE.

Comment: INNER JOIN sí funciona en [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html#idm45429437787680)

Comment: Toda la razón, mi error si se puede hacer un inner join.

Aún así, no habrá un modo de usar una variable en mysql del tipo @var= dato1,dato2,dato3 en un IN como lo muestro en el primer mensaje del hilo?